# eject a disk by path / volume name

Tags: mount, macintosh

I'm trying to eject a USB drive, e.g `/Volume/MyPassport`

I can do that with hdiutil, e.g `hdiutil eject /dev/disk5`. In that case I need to know the disk name of the target volume.

So I'd like to use the volume name instead, something like `hdiutil eject /Volume/MyPassport`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly that works for me on Mac OS X 10.11.

```
$ hdiutil create -size 128m -fs HFS+ blah    
...............................................................................
created: /private/var/tmp/blah.dmg
$ hdiutil mount blah.dmg                 
/dev/disk1              GUID_partition_scheme           
/dev/disk1s1            Apple_HFS                       /Volumes/untitled
$ df | grep unt
Filesystem   512-blocks      Used Available Capacity  iused   ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1     262064      6144    255920     3%      766   31990    2%   /Volumes/untitled
$ hdiutil eject /Volumes/untitled
"disk1" unmounted.
"disk1" ejected.
$ df | grep unt                  
Filesystem   512-blocks      Used Available Capacity  iused   ifree %iused  Mounted on
$
```